# Objective C Private Public Methods In Same Category

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What I'd like to do is separate a category's methods into private and public methods. The **private methods need to be visible outside of that category's file**, but not outside the class.

For instance, let's say I have the following files:

```
ClassA.m
ClassA.h // <-- Includes definitions of public category methods
ClassAPrivates.h // <-- Includes definition of private category methods.
ClassA+Render.m
```

`ClassAPrivates.h` would look like this:

```
@interface ClassA()
// private methods here, for use inside ClassA
@end
@interface ClassA(Render)
// the private methods of the Render category.
-(void)privateConfigureDeviceContext;
-(void)privateConfigureBufferSpace;
@end
```

And 'ClassA.h' would look like this:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
// public methods of ClassA
@end
@interface ClassA (Render)
// public methods of category Render
-(void)drawLine;
-(void)drawCircle;
@end
```

However, XCode complains about duplicate interface for Render. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create separate categories for private methods.

There are 3 scenarios:

1. `ClassA+Render.m` accessing the private methods that are defined in the `ClassA.m`
2. `ClassA.m` accessing the private methods that are defined in `ClassA+Render.m`
3. `ClassA+Render.m` accessing the properties defined in `ClassA.m`

*Note: Though the original poster hasn't asked for Scenario 3, I thought it might come in handy*

**Example**

`ClassA.m` defines 2 private methods

- `basePrivateMethod1` - This would invoke `renderPrivateMethod1`
- `basePrivateMethod2`

`ClassA+Render.m` defines 2 private methods

- `renderPrivateMethod1`
- `renderPrivateMethod2` - This would invoke `basePrivateMethod2`

**Scenario 1**

- In `ClassA+Render.m` just create an extension and forward declare the methods that you want to use.

**ClassA+Render.m**

```
@interface ClassA ()

- (void) basePrivateMethod1; //Just forward declare the method

@end
```

**Scenario 2**

- In `ClassA+Render.h` just declare the methods defined in `ClassA+Render.m`.
- In `ClassA.m` just include (`#import`) `ClassA+Render.h`
- Pls note, `ClassA+Render.h` would / should not be used outside of `ClassA`

**ClassA+Render.h**

```
@interface ClassA (Render)
{
    - (void) basePrivateMethod2;
}
```

**Scenario 3**

- Pls note - Properties can not be defined / created in the categories
- So create a new category called `ClassA+Properties`
- In `ClassA+Properties.h` redeclare all the properties
- In `ClassA+Properties.m` use `@dynamic` for all the properties to tell the compiler that the actual definition of these properties is else where
- In `ClassA+Render.m` include (`#import`) `ClassA+Properties.h`, so that all the properties are accessible

**ClassA+Properties.h**

```
@interface ClassA (Properties)
{
    @property NSUInteger property1;
    @property NSUInteger property2;
}
```

**ClassA+Properties.m**

```
@interface ClassA (Properties)
{
    @dynamic property1;
    @dynamic property2;
}
```

Comment: I'll be honest, I've long since abandoned using Objective-C on iOS in favor of C++11. Having said that, I've read your solution over multiple times, and whilst you may have found a solution for the trivial example given, I don't believe it still works if there were, say, a `ClassA+Clear.m` thrown into it, due to multiple anonymous category definitions (`@interface ClassA ()`).

Comment: I have used it in my project which has multiple categories. `@interface ClassA ()` is used in the .m (multiple) files and use it only to re-declare stuff, it doesn't redefine stuff. So while the linker links the all the object files, there would be one definition of the method.  When you want to use the methods of one category in another category simply import the header of the category in the .m file of the category that wants to use it.

Comment: You can declare as many times as you want just like forward declaration or extern variable, there would be only one definition (implementation), so it would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare Render's private methods in a class extension in its own file. This takes advantage that you can have multiple class extensions.

`ClassA.h`:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
// public methods of ClassA
@end
```

`ClassA+Render.h`:

```
@interface ClassA (Render)
// public methods of category Render
-(void)drawLine;
-(void)drawCircle;
@end
```

`ClassA+Render_Private.h`:

```
@interface ClassA ()
// the private methods of the Render category.
-(void)privateConfigureDeviceContext;
-(void)privateConfigureBufferSpace;
@end
```

Comment: oops, I just noticed I use `Raster` and `Render` as seperate words when they were intended to both be the same word, I edited my post to fix this. In your answer, you've got `ClassA+Raster.h` and `ClassA+Render.h` as separate files >.<

Comment: What I'm worried I might have to do is make a `PrivateRender` category, and a `PublicRender` category. However, I've got alot of categories as it is, and this would effectively double that number.

Answer (score 0):

You declare two categories named `Render` on `ClassA`.  That is why Xcode is complaining.

Comment: That is why it's complaining, but are you able to see what it was I was trying to accomplish? One of the definitions of the `Render` category contained only public methods, and the other definition of the `Render` category contained only private methods. I need to be able to separate the scope. It seems a weakness of the language if they have to ALL BE public, or ALL BE private.

Comment: I believe that I see you goal, and I would share your wish to avoid a proliferation of categories solely to limit scope, but why do private methods of a category need to be visible in a category interface at all?  For example, where do private methods of `ClassA (Render)` need to be visible?

Comment: Why do the private methods of `Render` need to visible from all of `ClassA`? Because there are other categories (for example, `RenderSphere`) that use some of the private methods that are in the category `Render`. In otherwords, `RenderSphere` might need to call `privateConfigureBufferSpace` for its spherical shenanigans.

Comment: I see. Then I'd probably say those methods aren't really private.  Or the difficulty may be suggesting a completely different alternative such as subclassing.  Or the use of a helper class to deal with cross-category implementation commonalities.

Comment: Where it's convenient, I do apply subclassing and helper classes (I'm certainly not trying to avoid their use) But I need to be able to apply scope rules in this case. It's looking like the best way to do that, in this case, is prefixing the category names: `(PrivateRender)` and `(Render)`. Fortunently this won't affect the number of files in the project, but the headers will be a bit more complicated (since there will be twice as many categories).

Answer (score 0):

Category is a concept which states any new method can be added to an existing class and all subclass will eventually get that method.

You use categories to define additional methods of an existing class—even one whose source code is unavailable to you—without subclassing. You typically use a category to add methods to an existing class, such as one defined in the Cocoa frameworks. **The added methods are inherited by subclasses** and are indistinguishable at runtime from the original methods of the class.

If you are adding private method, then why to go with category? As it can be used only by that single class file itself. Therefore why not to create a normal private method!!!

Comment: For the very next sentence that you omitted from [Apple Documentation on Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html):

`Using categories, you can also distribute the implementation of your own classes among several files.`